# Looking for open-source fashion design software

Tags: software-recommendation

I don't know anything about fashion design, but I've been getting
into streetwear and want to try and make some t-shirt and hat designs.

Now, I can obviously design in Inkscape, but I was wondering if there 
was any specific fashion design software available for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) is very cool -  http://wiki.blender.org/

[Manual](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual)

[Pre-Compiled plugins](http://www.blender.org/download/resources/)

#### Aimed world-wide at media professionals and artists.

Blender can be used to create 3D visualizations, stills as well as broadcast and cinema quality videos, while the incorporation of a real-time 3D engine allows for the creation of 3D interactive content for stand-alone playback.

[image: Example of Blender output]